# How do I avoid smart pricing?

Tags: google-adsense

I heard that if your website/blog receives few views, you should avoid putting ads on the site due to smart pricing.

I have a number of niche sites (all with ads) and am just now opening another niche site. I'm wondering how long I should wait before I put AdSense on it (it's been quite a while since I've started a niche site.)

How many views should you have per day on your site before you put ads on to avoid being smart priced?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "smart pricing"?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: a way for Adsense to pay you even less peanuts than the already few peanuts it was paying you before. :-) More info here: http://www.nichepursuits.com/how-to-avoid-smart-pricing-on-google-adsense/#

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend adsense as a last resort. If you truly want to make something of your blogs link them to each other and build yourself a good traffic between the blog network. Use one blog as ad on another. Thereby building a fantastic flow of traffic and retaining visitors within your network. This will compliment all your sites

Remember the most ignored downfall of ads on a site: They lead the visitors OUT/Exit not bring them in. Unless ads can offer the visitors something relatively useful to what your site and their interests are then they are just ugly or loss of visitors.

It would be much better to use affiliate marketing links/ads which are related to your site content.

Placing ads is advisable when you have a regular traffic coming in month by month but the affiliate conversion are not getting higher.

There is no specific number but I have found that if you are getting over 100K impressions a month for an ad zone you can get placements which bring in higher revenues than bulk/network ads.

Source: Personal 8 years of experience plus advertiser's perspective.

Comment: What if my sites are completely unrelated to each other?

Comment: well actually the adsense ads are unrelated as well. Difference is that ads from adsense use tracking cookie. so somehow there is interest involved. But it is entirely possible that you can find "related" sites in your basket or randomize the site links.

It is true that relates sites are more likely to get clicks.

End of the day smart pricing is really calculated based on keyword traffic ratios. A less searched keyword or display network will always smart price. Only large traffic sites get direct placements.

There is a post on google explaining whats smart pricing (adwords/adsense help)

Comment: @Melanie Take StackExchange as an example: Amateur Radio and Webmasters have nothing to do with each other, but they're connected as they're part of the StackExchange network...

Answer (score 0):

Another option to AdSense and affiliate ads, is to try and find an ad network specializing in your niche.

Most smaller, (or large but extremely premium) ad networks will try and sell your inventory (traffic) in CPM blocks, so you'd be selling 100,000 page views for x dollars. At a set rate, so smart pricing is not really a factor.

The other benefit with this is that because the ad space costs more they tend to be better ads (for both your site and your visitors). As better advertisers are the ones who can afford it.

I'm not sure of the niche of your website but for design and development ad networks you should check out sites like http://carbonads.net/ or http://fusionads.net/

Alternatively http://buysellads.com/ is a great site to sell space specifically tailored to your niche as they work as a marketplace for loads of different niches.